# Duplicated node pages are created with other language prefixes. How to fix it?

Tags: nodes

The content on our website is primarily created in English, however, we also have 3 other languages (fr, de, es) implemented. But not all the content is translated.

The problem is - in Google, we see a lot of duplicated pages with de/fr/es language prefix being as Node/id BUT the content is in English and the translation of the page doesn't exist. Basically de/es don't exist but they are somehow indexed by Google.

For example:
Original page path alias - en/blog/text (node id 134)
Duplicated page with English content path alias - de/node/134 - es/node/134

de/es duplicated nodes have also self-canonical and no correct hreflang because as mentioned above these pages don't exist as translations. This is harmful for SEO as Google sees these pages as duplicates.

Is there a way to avoid the creation of such pages? How it can be fixed?

Thank you!

Comment: How they got indexed then? Sitemap? I might remember some setting in one of our sitemaps "exclude untranslated nodes", but unsure. Unfortunately they are indexed now and I think you'd need to build some custom redirect module that redirects when no translation exists to the default language node.

Comment: There is nothing to fix, this is by design. The "duplicated" pages have a `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="..." href="..." />`, so there is no duplicate content. Even if the content is not translated, all the other stuff around it (blocks, menus, UI words,...) is translated, so there is a reason this URL exists.

Comment: What Drupal version? There is a difference in handling translated nodes between D7 and D8.